# Need to throw error messages if path to an external app doesn't exist in Java

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

I have 4 jButtons that execute each specific program ([Browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTWP5.png) for the time being), I need to make a conditional that tells a user that if a path to that specific program doesn't exist it will open a webpage with that specific browser in mind.

This piece of code repeats itself and I need to optimise it. I tried making another method where I would use if statement but instead it just gave me a lot of issues while executing each button.

Warning_MSG(); is just another method with jOptionPane to confirm if a user wants to open an external application, etc etc.

```
private void chromeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
  
    File file = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
    if(!file.exists()){
       try {
         URI url = new URI("https://google.com/chrome"); 
         java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url);
         System.err.println("File Error, Google Chrome is not found!\n");
            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
              System.err.println("Unknown Error, Exception found\n" + e);
             }
    }else {
        Warning_MSG(file);
    }
    
}                                   

private void firefoxMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    File file = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    if(!file.exists()){
       try {
         System.err.println("File Error, Mozilla Firefox is not found!\n");
         URI url = new URI("https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/download/thanks/"); 
         java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url);
            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
             System.err.println("Unknown Error, Exception found\n" + e);
             }
    }else {
        Warning_MSG(file);
    }
    
}                                    

private void ieMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
    File file = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
   if(!file.exists()){
      System.err.println("File Error, iExplorer is not found! \n");
    }else {
        Warning_MSG(file);
    }
    
}                               

private void edgeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
    File file = new File("C:\\Windows\\SystemApps\\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\MicrosoftEdge.exe");
 if(!file.exists()){
       System.err.println("File Error, Microsoft Edge is not Found! \n");
    }else {
        Warning_MSG(file);
    }
    
}
```

The question is, how can I optimise these pieces of code so that I don't have to repeat the same thing all over again with other programs but instead run certain things only when conditions are met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an enum with 2 parameters (exe path, download page)

```
enum Browser
{
    Chrome("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "https://google.com/chrome"),
    Firefox("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/download/thanks/"),
    IExplorer("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe", "https://google.com/internet-explorer"),
    Edge("C:\\Windows\\SystemApps\\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\MicrosoftEdge.exe", "https://google.com/download-edge");
    
    private final String _filePath, _downloadPageURL;
    
    Browser(String filePath, String downloadPage)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
        _downloadPageURL = downloadPage;
    }
    
    private String getDownloadPageURL()
    {
        return _downloadPageURL;
    }
    
    private String getFilePath()
    {
        return _filePath;
    }
    
    public boolean exists()
    {
        return new File(getFilePath()).exists();
    }
    
    public void openDownloadPage()
    {
        try
        {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(getDownloadPageURL()));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, all you have to do is a simple check at your methods.

```
private void chromeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{
    final Browser chrome = Browser.Chrome;
    if (!chrome.exists())
    {
        chrome.openDownloadPage();
        System.err.println("File Error, Google Chrome is not found!\n");
        return;
    }
    
    // The browser exists at this line. So create your code
    // ...
}
```